# Local function in JavaScript object with namespace

Tags: javascript

I want to create a namespace to organise all of my JavaScript. I can't see a way, using the code sample below, to create a local function so that it can't be called except from within this Object.

```
window.JD = window.JD || {};

JD.Guid = {

    newGuid : function() {
        return JD.Guid.s4(); // Would like this to be this.s4();
    },

    s4 : function() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
    }
}
```

I have tried using `JD.Guid = function() {...}` but that doesn't work either. The console tells me that the function is undefined.

I'd like to be able to call `JD.Guid.newGuid()` from anywhere within my site.

Comment: Try:console.log(JD.Guid.newGuid());

Comment: How do you want to access your function?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyAW. Question updated.

Comment: if your local scope (because you want to call from anywhere) have `JD` then try calling `window.JD.Guid.newGuid()`, otherwise, I don't see anything wrong, you can actually call `JD.Guid.newGuid()` from anywhere in your site, (if no 'JD' is there in the current scope or parent hierarchy scope apart from the window's one)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about `module` design pattern and in this case your code must looks like:

```
window.JD = window.JD || {};
JD.Guid = (function () {
    // This function is private,
    // you can re-use it only from public accessible method.
    var privateMethod = function() {
        return 'private';
    };
    return {
        newGuid : function() {
            return JD.Guid.s4();
        },
        newGuidThroughtThis : function() {
            return this.s4();
        },
        privateMethod: function() {
            return privateMethod();
        },
        s4 : function() {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
        }
    }
})();
```

Now you can re-use your module and do something like:

```
console.log(JD.Guid.s4());
console.log(JD.Guid.newGuid());
console.log(JD.Guid.newGuidThroughtThis());
```

as output you'll get something like: 118723

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for and found this link which may help others in the future https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Comment: Cool! Yes, link is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm following. But you can create a local function which is not accessible in global namespace by creating a context wrapping your code in a function:

```
(function() {
  window.JD = window.JD || {};

  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
  }

  JD.Guid = {
    newGuid: function() {
      return s4();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Yes it does although another answer talks about the `module` design pattern, which is exactly the sort of thing I'm after. Your answer does match the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
var JD = (function(GLOBAL_JD){
      if(GLOBAL_JD === undefined) {
        var jd = {
          GUID: {
            newGuid: newGuid          
          }
        };

        return jd;
      }

  function newGuid() {
    return s4(); // Would like this to be this.s4();
  }

  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
  }
})(JD);

console.log(JD.GUID.newGuid());
```

http://jsbin.com/jodifeb/edit?js,console,output